403 Forbidden when trying to call Graph API to add calendar event
I have a working ASP.NET Core Web Application, which successfully can get a graphClient and call the graph API (for example can create OnLineMeeting) using C#
However if I try to create a Calendar event I got an exception

"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

(when debugging with Fiddler the response is 403 Forbidden accordingly)

Within the very same application using the very same graphClient everything is working for Graph API OnlineMeetings calls, so all configuration, OpenID supposedly OK.
My user can interactively create Calendar events, and has Teams license
I log in to the Web Application with this "my user" using the Entra ID tenant OpenIDConnect (see code below)
The Azure App Registration has consented Calendar.ReadWrite API permission for both Delegated and Application (see picture below)
I am using literally the copied C# tab from this tutorial Example 4: Create and enable an event as an online meeting (Scroll down to Example 4, switch to C#)

What I've done so far:
What is suspicious for me, if I debug the request with fiddler, and decode the access token what _graphClient puts to the header, I do not see the Calendar.ReadWrite scope in the scopes...
{
    ...
    "scp": "Chat.Create Chat.Read Chat.ReadBasic Chat.ReadWrite email OnlineMeetingRecording.Read.All OnlineMeetings.Read OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite openid profile User.Read",
    ...
}

Question:
Why I got Access Denied? If the answer is the the missing scope, then how to add the Calendar Scopes? (to be honest I do not understand why those scopes in the scp claim, I did not specified those explicitly...)
Further diagnostics info:
API Permissions for the Application Registration:

Code in the Program.cs, after that I can get graphClient using DI
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphV1"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


Are you making use of Client credential flow?

The screenshot shows Calendars.ReadWrite delegated permission has not received admin consent.

@Rukmini: I suppose, the code part in the program.cs does that, it requires in the appsettings.json the clientid, clientsecret and the tenantid.  But it seems I authenticating myself as "my user" also, because when I navigate to the Web App, it redirect me to MS login. Btw, both Application and Delegated permissions are given to the Calendar API

@g.pickardou as you are making use of delegated flow, you need to grant admin consent to Calendars.ReadWrite to reflect the scope

@g.pickardou the last column says "Granted for..." for all other permissions but not that one

All OK, I cannot believe how I did not notice the missing consent. Working now. Many thx.

To create Calendar event, you need to grant admin consent to Calendars.ReadWrite delegated API permission:

Hence to resolve the error, make sure to grant admin consent to Calendars.ReadWrite permission
Make sure the permission reflects in the access token scope like below:

For sample, I created calendar event successfully for the signed in user like below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-type: application/json

{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does noon work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2024-05-15T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2024-05-15T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"xxx@contoso.com",
        "name": "User"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
  "transactionId":"7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A7"
}


If you want to create calendar event for any other user, then grant Calendars.ReadWrite.All delegated API permission
Note that:

For client credential flow (non-user interactive flow) grant Application type permissions.
For delegated flow (user interactive flow) grant delegated type permissions.

